# How to display a few option in columns at menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I want do a menu like on this site: http://www.accenture.com/us-en/pages/index.aspx ex. outsourcing. It's possible to do this using css and html. I can't create "li" or "ul" with columns.

My code

```
<body>

<style type="text/css">#cssmenu{
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:verdana,geneva,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:8e8e8e;
    }
#cssmenu ul{
    background:url(menu_assets/images/menu-bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
    height:43px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    #cssmenu li{
        float:left;
        padding:0px 8px 0px 8px;
        }
    #cssmenu li a{
        color:#666666;
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:43px;
        padding:0px 25px;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
        #cssmenu li a:hover{
            color:#000000;
            text-decoration:underline;
            }
    #cssmenu li ul{
        background:#e0e0e0;
        border-left:1px solid #0079b2;
        border-right:1px solid #0079b2;
        border-bottom:1px solid #0079b2;
        display:none;
        height:auto;
        filter:alpha(opacity=95);
        opacity:0.95;
        position:absolute;
        width:600px;
        /*top:1em;
        /*left:0;*/
        }
    #cssmenu li:hover ul{
        display:block;
        }
    #cssmenu li li {
        display:block;
        float:none;
        padding:0px;
        width:225px;
        }
    #cssmenu li ul a{
        display:block;
        font-size:12px;
        font-style:normal;
        padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
        text-align:left;
        }
        #cssmenu li ul a:hover{
            background:#949494;
            color:#000000;
            opacity:1.0;
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);
            }
    #cssmenu p{
        clear:left;
        }   
    #cssmenu .active > a{
        background:url(menu_assets/images/current-bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
        color:#ffffff;
        }
    #cssmenu .active > a:hover {
        color:#ffffff;
        }
        </style>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 4</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both; margin: 0 0 30px 0;">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
```

Of course I search on web but I can't find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specific selectors**

First off, when you use a CSS rule like `#cssmenu ul` or `#cssmenu li`, that CSS rule will get applied to the HTML tags for both the main menu and the sub-menus. Some of the styles may be getting applied to elements where they don't need to be applied. To avoid this possible confusion, use the `>` child combinator in more of the CSS selectors. For example:

```
#cssmenu > ul {...}           // Only applied to main menu
#cssmenu > ul > li {...}      // Only applied to main menu li tags
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {...}  // Only applied to main menu links

#cssmenu ul ul {...}       // No confusion here, since menu isn't 3 levels deep
#cssmenu ul ul li {...}    // No confusion here, only applied to submenu li tags
#cssmenu ul ul li a {...}  // No confusion here, only applied to submenu links
```

**Floating the menu items**

Second, if you're imitating the [Accenture menu](http://www.accenture.com/us-en/pages/index.aspx), the quickest way to display variable-width menu items on the right side of the page is to float the menu items to the left while floating the menu as a whole to the right.

```
#cssmenu > ul      { float: right; ... }
#cssmenu > ul > li { float: left; ... }
...
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a> ... </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Sometimes floating a parent and child in opposite directions is problematic. If you have any trouble doing so, the safest option is to float the menu items to the right. In that case, to get them to display in the correct order, you'll have to reverse the order of the menu items in the HTML source code.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li { float: right; ... }
...
<ul>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a> ... </li>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
</ul>
```